# Multiple transitions inside .css()

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to get multiple sets of transitions into a jQuery CSS Object. In CSS I would write it down like this:

**css**

```
transition:
    opacity 600ms cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1),
    -webkit-transform 350ms cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1),
    transform 350ms cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1);
```

But as you can see below, this won't work in jQuery because of the comma ',' I guess?

**jQuery**

```
$('.current-slide').css({
    'transition':
        'opacity 600ms cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1),
        -webkit-transform 350ms cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1),
        transform 350ms cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1)',
    'opacity': '0',
    'z-index': '1',
    '-webkit-transform': 'scale(.8) translateY(0)',
    'transform': 'scale(.8) translateY(0)'
});
```

Tried to find some useful info about this problem online, but I can't find any. Thanks!

Comment: At least one reason the code as quoted won't work is that it's a syntax error to have an unescaped newline in a normal string literal.

Comment: Once you fix that, I have no idea if `css()` supports this or not, but it seems like it would be a better idea to define this transition on a class and add that class to the element rather than inline styling.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thank you, it didn't work by the way, when I put the 4 lines in one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution try this code

```
$('.current-slide').css({
    'transition': 'opacity 600ms cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1),-webkit-transform 350ms cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1),transform 350ms cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1)',
    'opacity': '0',
    'z-index': '1',
    '-webkit-transform': 'scale(.8) translateY(0)',
    'transform': 'scale(.8) translateY(0)',
});
```

don't brake the line ..